# Shortcode in iframe url

Tags: wordpress, iframe, shortcode

im trying to use shortcode for tracking in iframe and links urls but iframe is ignoring the shortcode. Can some1 help me with that? Thanks!
I have shortcode function like this:

```
function myShortcode(){
  return 'test';
}
add_shortcode( 'tracking', 'myShortcode' );
```

if i put link to content like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/?tracking=[tracking]">Tracking link</a>
```

it returns link with tracking info like: http://example.com/?tracking=test (correct)

but when i use it in iframe like this

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/iframe/?tracking=[tracking]"></iframe>
```

it return link inside like this: http://example.com/iframe/?tracking=[tracking] (incorrect - missing 'test' value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are doing wrong way.

After register your shortcode you have to use `do_shortcode` function to display that shortcode as output.

If you are use your iframe or anchor text as plain html then try like this.

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/iframe/?tracking=<?php echo do_shortcode( '[bradford]' ); ?>"></iframe>
```

And I'm not sure why anchort text display right output. That's weird.

Anyway if you used `do_shortcode` to output your shortcode then it will work every place.

See Here for more info [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

***Updated***

I see you tried your shortcode this way on `wp_editor`. anyway I don't that will work. but you can see it work on anchor link but not on the iframe, actually iframe always special case, some how WordPress can't handle this one on iframe.

After some research I came to solution for this, actually if you open wp-includes/kses.php then you will find some hints about it. WordPress by default not allow iframe in kses allow HTML list. and maybe that's why it not working properly but anchor text are allow on that list that's why it's working perfectly.

So you have to allow iframe by using [wp_kses_allowed_html()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_allowed_html)

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'wpse_allow_iframe_kses_html',1,1 );
function wpse_allow_iframe_kses_html( $allowedposttags ) {

  // Here add tags and attributes you want to allow
  $allowedposttags['iframe']=array(
    'align' => true,
    'width' => true,
    'height' => true,
    'frameborder' => true,
    'name' => true,
    'src' => true,
    'id' => true,
    'class' => true,
    'style' => true,
    'scrolling' => true,
    'marginwidth' => true,
    'marginheight' => true,
    'allowfullscreen' => true,
  );
  return $allowedposttags;

}
```

Now you can see the different.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Im using this shortcode in classic wordpress content editor (imho you cant use PHP tags here).

Comment: @bohusnov I update my answer please try and let me know. It's really interesting you know, I think it's a bug of the WordPress (I'm not exactly sure of it).

Comment: If you're using the shortcode in the editor, there is no way to add php to parse it manually - we need a different/generic solution to this.